# Two different formulations for the Euler-Lagrange equation on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I just find two different ways of formulating the Euler-Lagrange equation on Riemannian manifolds. Let's start with a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and a Lagrangian $L:\mathbf R\times TM\to\mathbf R$. We use the [generalized coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates#Generalized_coordinates) $(q^i,\dot q^i)$ on $TM$.

The first one is the common one, which can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Generalization_to_manifolds):
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q^i} (t,q(t), \dot q(t)) \right) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^i} (t,q(t), \dot q(t)).
\end{equation}
It makes use of the integration by parts in coordinates.

The second one can be found in [Page 153 of Villani's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-71050-9):
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\frac{D}{dt}\Big( \nabla_{\dot q} L(t,q(t), \dot q(t)) \Big) = \nabla_q L(t,q(t), \dot q(t)),
\end{equation}
where $\frac{D}{dt}$ stands for the covariant derivative along $q(t)$; $\nabla_q$ and $\nabla_{\dot q}$ are the gradient with respect to the position variable $q$ and velocity variable $\dot q$ respectively, under the Riemannian tensor $g$. This way adopts the integration by parts for covariant derivatives.

Obviously, $(1)$ and $(2)$ do not coincide. So I am really confused about which one is the right one? And what is the relation between these two equations?

TIA...

Comment: Note that it is possible to define a Lagrangian that does not use any Riemannian metric or even any connection. So there has to be a way to write the Euler-Lagrange equations without using any connection.

Comment: @Deane Thank you. That is true. What you are saying is just the equation (1), without any connection. But why Villani wrote the E-L equation in the fashion with a connection?

Comment: Presumably, Villani is working in a situation where there is a Riemannian metric that plays a central role in the study of the Lagrangian. Often, there is more than one way to write a formula, and the one you choose depends on the context.

Comment: @Deane But for a given action with a given Lagrangian, how could its minimizing curves satisfy two different equations?

Comment: Well, there's an obvious answer to that. When two equations have the exact same solutions, then what's the conclusion?

Comment: @Deane It is true for the situation that $L=\frac{1}{2} |\dot q|^2 + V(q)$, while I suspect that it is not for more general cases. I am not sure and I will think about this aspect. Thank you very much professor!

Comment: Related Phys.SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/239974/2451